# Run gauge java specs with headless chrome inside a docker container

Tags: java, docker, google-chrome-headless, getgauge

I am trying to run a set of gauge specs with headless chrome inside a docker container.

I've tried setting up a Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM maven:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y unzip curl

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# requirements for chrome headless
# https://github.com/Googlechrome/puppeteer/issues/290#issuecomment-322838700
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg &&\
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash - &&\
apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs make g++ &&\
apt-get update &&\
apt-get install -y git-all gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
  libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 \
  libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 \
  libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates \
  fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget &&\
apt autoremove -y &&\
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Install Google Chrome
RUN curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install google-chrome-stable && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install gauge
RUN apt-get install unzip
RUN curl -L https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/releases/download/v1.0.5/gauge-1.0.5-linux.x86_64.zip -o /gauge-1.0.5-linux.x86_64.zip
RUN unzip -o gauge-1.0.5-linux.x86_64.zip -d /usr/local/bin

# Install gauge plugins
RUN gauge install java && \
    gauge install screenshot

ENTRYPOINT ["mvn"]
```

NOTE: There was a small amount of proprietary stuff in here I have had to remove, but it shouldn't make a difference.

Also note the CI system where I work takes care of lots of stuff, e.g. mounting volumes into the container, fetching repositories from git, assigning ports etc etc.

When the CI system uses this container to run the gauge specs they all fail with errors like so:

```
 INFO: Created user preferences directory.
17:55:37  Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8 (681f24ea911fe754973dda2fdc6d2a2e159dd300-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#40}) on port 26120
17:55:37  Only local connections are allowed.
17:55:37  Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
17:55:37  [1560441336.946][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
17:55:37  Failed to take regular screenshot: 
17:55:37  No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
17:55:37  Failed to take regular screenshot: 
17:55:37  No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
17:55:37      Error Message: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
17:55:37        (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
17:55:37        (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
17:55:37      Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
17:55:37      System info: host: 'dae4cd1c9fcd', ip: '10.99.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-1029-gcp', java.version: '11.0.1'
17:55:37      Driver info: driver.version: GaugeDriver
17:55:37      remote stacktrace: #0 0x562fab6bd299 <unknown>
```

So it appears the headless chrome instance doesn't even start. However, I cannot work out why.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing --no-sandbox option to the chromedriver instance.

**Example:**

```
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.addArguments(“--no-sandbox”);
   new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4961) issue fro more details.